# Estimate the distribution variance for small sampling size

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, central-limit-theorem, sampling

In the case of distribution with a large population size $N \ge 10000$, which follows an unusual distribution with stand deviation $\sigma$. By the central limit theorem, repeat sampling with a large sampling size $n \geq 30$, the sample mean $\mu_{\bar{x}}$ would follow the sample distribution $~\mathcal{N}(\mu_{\bar{x}}, \sigma_{\bar{x}})$ where $\sigma_{\bar{x}} = \sigma/\sqrt{n}$ is the standard deviation of the sampling distribution.

However, for a small sampling size $n\leq 10$, is there a proper way to calculate the standard deviation of the sampling distribution $\sigma_{\bar{x}}$ by directly calculating from the given population instead of sampling? Since the sampling distribution does not exactly follow a gaussian for small $n$.

Comment: Even for larger $N$, the distribution is not EXACTLY normal, but the approximation gets better and better with increasing $N$. As you say, this approximation is bad for very small $N$, so the central limit theorem cannot be applied well.

Comment: @Peter You are right, it is less accurate to use this approximation for small $n$.

Comment: You will need to do it case by case. In other words, you will start with a distribution $F$ on $\mathbf{R}$ and then consider its covolutional power $F^{\ast n}$ where $n$ is your (small) sample size. Excepting a few common distributions, $F^{\ast n}$ will not have a closed form and something like resampling (a.k.a. bootstrap) will probably help.

Comment: @WilliamM. Does it mean that the convolution power can calculate the sampling distribution?

Comment: The most basic example is a Bernoulli trial. If you have $n = 10$ such trials, then the convolutional power of $n = 10$ Bernoulli trials with unknown success probability $p$ is the binomial distribution with $n = 10$ trials and probability of success $p.$ In that case, you'd do inference directly on the binomial distribution. Other example is you also start with Bernoulli trials but this time you record the number of trials needed until you reach $n = 10$ successes. This is a Negative Binomial distribution. Hypergeometric, Geometric, etc also arise in similar ways. But in general, it is hard.

Comment: For your second paragraph with small $n$ you'd have to know the variance or SD of the population dist'n, or you'd have to use your small sample to estimate it. (Both often problematic in practice.)